# How can I make a registered user's encrypted password be accepted as the normal password when logging in?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I recently created a register page where a user can sign up and create their own account. But say if I log out and then go back into the account and try logging in only the encrypted version of the password is accepted. How can I make my loguserin function talk to my database and have it understand that it's actually a normal password the user orignally entered?

Controller:

```
 function loguserin()
 {

$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|callback_validateUser|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');


if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);

    redirect('home');
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'NOT_OK');
    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('account/logintitle');
    $this->load->view('account/loginview');
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');
}
 }



  function validateUser($username, $password)
  {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('membership');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password',MD5($password));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query ->num_rows ==1)
    {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('validateUser', 'Invalid username/password');

    return false;
}

else{

    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: "encrypted password" — please don't ever have an actually encrypted password. Passwords are *hashed*, not *encrypted*.

Comment: MD5 is obsolete, please move to Blowfish. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: Well the password looks this way in the database - 811584043b844704c9bb9a6e99dd05d3 is this not encrypted?

Comment: It's encrypted; but not secure. A look-up in a rainbow table could quickly find most common passwords. For example; your password is 'gaga'. **I just googled the MD5 hash - does that sound secure?.**

Comment: @FergusMorrow It is *not* encrypted. It is (poorly) hashed.

Comment: Yeah, I used encrypted for lack of a better word. You're 100% correct @PeeHaa.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending upon what hashing you are using to store the password, your model confitions would be something like this:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('membership');
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
```

Also, there is a bug in your model for checking if a user is valid. If number of rows returned from DB is 1, then the user is valid, otherwise not.

```
if ($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

else
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('validateUser', 'Invalid username/password');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhi that worked, but how can i make my users not be able to log in if they havent signed up yet? My validateUser function is supposed to stop nonregistered users from logging in but it doesn't. Please check my amended code above

Comment: I added some code for the problem you just mentioned. Its a logic error in your code. Also once this starts working as expected, you should look into other ways of hashing as other folks have suggested.

Comment: thanks Abhi that threw up the error but believe it or not none of my registered users can now log in, what could this be do you think? Could it be the if else statement in my loguserin function?

Comment: try putting a `var_dump($valid);` after the `$valid = $this->validateUser($username, $password);` line. That will tell if the problem is in model or controller.

Comment: I have put in a var dump  for this and I just seemed to get null values back - how could this be?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your problem is that at registration passwords are hashed because of security considerations.

In this case you must know what hashing function was used. For example [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php). Than you should simply crypt the user input before doing the query.

```
    $hashedPassword = crypt($password);
    $this->db->select('*')->from('membership');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $hashedPassword);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) are PHP's recommendations for password hashing.

Answer (score 1):

It would perhaps appear that CodeIgniter isn't encrypting the password with MD5; as specified in `set_rules()`:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');
```

One way to verify this would be to dump the contents of it to the display. For example..

```
var_dump( $this->input->post('password') );
```

If the password appears to be plain text still; then set_rules hasn't ran md5() on the variable and that will take some troubleshooting.

For future reference, generally an authentication system will have the user details in a database; including a hashed version of the password and username. The PHP application will launch a SQL command like `SELECT password FROM users WHERE USERNAME=username`; **if no row is returned then the username is incorrect**.

Then the user input is ran through a hashing method - this is compared with the value retrieved from the database. *If these don't match then the password is wrong*.

However you appear to be sending both the password and username in the database query; whilst this will work - you wont be able to determine whether it's an incorrect username or an incorrect password causing an authentication issue.

For reasons like this, it's often best to...

#### Try and Use an Authentication Framework

At the risk of being shot down; don't try and write your own authentication code for production projects. It just takes one small over-sight and you could compromise your whole application, user data and so on.

There are some really good *tried and tested* authentication frameworks out there - my favourite being [ion auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) for it's simplicity. However, you may find others you like more.

#### Dont just *encrypt* passwords; hash them.

It may sound like a subtle difference; but it's actually very important. In the (rather cruddy as it is!) event of your database being compromised - having your passwords hashed provides better security. Especially when attacks like rainbow-tables are concerned.

Similarly, don't use `md5()` - PHP has the [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function which will try and use a more secure algorithm - *if its available on the system*. Furthermore, it accepts a second argument (which is optional, but should be used) - the *salt*.

It's worth remembering that [`set_rules()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) can use `crypt()`; at least in it's simplest form (with one argument). From the documentation:

> Any native PHP function that accepts one parameter can be used as a rule, like htmlspecialchars, trim, MD5, etc.